# Spring/Hibernate not persisting all data submited from HTML Form

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate, spring-mvc, submit

In my current spring pŕoject, I have a form like that:

```
<form role="form" class="form" id="form" method="post" action="/loja/pagina/insert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="id" />

        <label>Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" />

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#pt-BR" aria-controls="pt-BR" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">pt-BR</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#es-ES" aria-controls="es-ES" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">es-ES</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#en-US" aria-controls="en-US" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">en-US</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpane1" class="tab-pane active" id="pt-BR">
            <input type="hidden" name="textos.idioma" value="pt-BR" />
            <textarea class="summernote" name="textos.conteudo"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div role="tabpane1" class="tab-pane" id="es-ES">
            <input type="hidden" name="textos.idioma" value="es-ES" />
            <textarea class="summernote" name="textos.conteudo"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div role="tabpane1" class="tab-pane" id="en-US">
            <input type="hidden" name="textos.idioma" value="en-US" />
            <textarea class="summernote" name="textos.conteudo"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

When I submit this form to this methods:

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'insert_'+#this.this.name)")
public void insert(@Valid E object, BindingResult result) {
    serv.insert(object);
}
```

**service**

```
@Transactional
public void insert(E object) {
    dao.insert(object);
}
```

**dao**

```
@Transactional
public void insert(E object) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(object);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Only the field `titulo` is persisted. the field `textos` , which is represented by this entity class (getters and setter omitted):

```
@Entity
public class Texto extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String idioma;

    @Column
    private String conteudo;
}
```

is not saved on the database. Anyone can tell what's the right way to implement the form to properly store this data? I check the browser's developer tools, and the data is being submitted, it's only not being persisted in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint given to me by the user @AnsgarSchulte in this question, I change the html code in the form for `name="textos[0]` and change my PropertyEditorSupport class to handle this array and return a `Texto` object with the property `idioma` being the first element of the vector and the property `conteudo` being all the elements left (concatenating all of them in one string).

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that your model class `Texto` has a @OneToMany relation to class `E`, so that one E references multiple instances of Texto. If this is what your model expresses, you have to use a different syntax for your textarea names to Spring being able to parse your request payload.

In your case Spring would search for a property textos.conteudo on your class E. As I assume, that textos will be a collection, Spring will ignore this.

Assuming, that textos will be modeled as an indexed based collection like List, try to rename your textareas names to `name="textos[0].conteudo"`  and so on to tell Spring that textos is a List and Spring will be able to parse the POST payload.